# java calculator loop not working properly

Tags: java, calculator

For some reason my calculator won't wait for user input to finish the do while loop. I'm very new to java coding (currently only been doing it for a few hours). I want the user to be able to do more math before the program closes instead of having to reopen it every time they want to use it (obviously I don't mean anything serious by this I just want to learn and I think this will help.

heres my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class calculator {
public static void main(String[] args){
    double Answer;
    String op;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    String again;
    boolean yesorno = true;

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

             while (yesorno = true){
                System.out.print("What opperation would you like to preform? +,-,*,/, :");
                op = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("What is the first number? : ");
                num1 = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("And the seccond number? : ");
                num2 = input.nextDouble();
                if (op.equals("+")) {
                    Answer = (num1 + num2);
                    System.out.println(Answer);

                } else if (op.equals("-")) {
                    Answer = num1 - num2;
                    System.out.println(Answer);

                } else if (op.equals("*")) {
                    Answer = num1 * num2;
                    System.out.println(Answer);

                } else if (op.equals("/")) {
                    Answer = num1 / num2;
                    System.out.println(Answer);

                }
                System.out.println("Would you like to do any more math?");
                again = input.nextLine();
                if (again.equals("yes")) {
                    yesorno = true;
                } else if (again.equals("no")) {
                    yesorno = false;
                    System.out.print("have a good day!");

                }
            } while (yesorno = true);       
}
}
```

please ignore the akward formatting at the beggining and end of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `while(yesorno = true )` you are doing **assignation** 
change to 
`while(yesorno == true)` to prevent this thing you can use yoda style `while(true = yesorno)` then a compile error would throw cause you can't assign something to a value.
Or even more simpler just use `while(yesorno)`

2) Follow [Java Code Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) , variable names are in lower case.

3)if this block get executed `while (yesorno = true);` you will have an infinite loop.

4) If you are using java 7 , you can do switch over strings

```
             switch(op){
             case "+":answer = num1 + num2;break;
             case "-":answer = num1 - num2;break;
             case "*":answer = num1 * num2;break;
             case "/":answer = num1 / num2;break;
             default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid operation "+ op);
             }
             System.out.println(answer);
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but I would suggest putting your `case`, `answer = ` and `break` statements on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are *assigning*, not *testing* for equality in `while (yesorno = true){`. You should use `while (yesorno == true){`, since the double equals (`==`) *tests* for equality.

Comment: that's not true, == test if they are pointing to the same object , equality only for primitives.

Comment: Quite true! Probably the distinction is lost on OP, but good on you for pointing it out.

Comment: @nachokk boolean is a primitive. Primitives are usually written lower case and classes upper case.

Answer (score 0):

There were many errors, I have fixed it and commented it for you. Hope it helps:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// KK: by general convention class names should always start with an upper case letter
public class calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double Answer; //KK: local variable should be lower case
        String op;
        double num1;
        double num2;
        String again;
        boolean yesorno = true;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //KK: for comparing you need the double-equals
        //KK: the loop will be executed as long as the expression is true, so for a boolean you don't need it at all
        //KK: you can use either of the following:
        // while (yesorno == true)
        // while (yesorno)
        while (yesorno) {
            System.out.print("What opperation would you like to preform? +,-,*,/, :");
            op = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("What is the first number? : ");
            num1 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("And the seccond number? : ");
            num2 = input.nextDouble();
            if (op.equals("+")) {
                Answer = (num1 + num2);
                System.out.println(Answer);

            } else if (op.equals("-")) {
                Answer = num1 - num2;
                System.out.println(Answer);

            } else if (op.equals("*")) {
                Answer = num1 * num2;
                System.out.println(Answer);

            } else if (op.equals("/")) {
                Answer = num1 / num2;
                System.out.println(Answer);

            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to do any more math?");
            //KK: you need to call nextLine twice because you printed 2 lines here
            //KK: otherwise again will be empty, so yesorno will always be true and you have an endless loop
            again = input.nextLine();
            again = input.nextLine();
            if (again.equals("yes")) {
                yesorno = true;
            } else if (again.equals("no")) {
                yesorno = false;
                System.out.print("have a good day!");
            }
        }
        // KK: the following line was an empty loop, that didn't do anything, so I commented it
        // while (yesorno = true);

    }
} //KK: this one was missing at the end too ;)
```

(I started my comments with KK, so you see them and can remove them later.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean status = true;
    while(status){

    String answer = "";
    String choise = "";

    System.out.println("\"WELCOME TO JAVA CALCULATOR\"");

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner cal = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner cho = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the numers one by one that you want to calculate..");
    int numA = scn.nextInt();
    int numB = scn.nextInt();
    int result = 0;
    System.out.println("What you want to calculate...?");
    answer = cal.nextLine();

    if(answer.equals("+")){
        result = numA+numB;}
    if(answer.equals("-")){
        result = numA-numB;}
    if(answer.equals("*")){
        result = numA*numB;}
    if(answer.equals("/")){
        result = numA/numB;}
    System.out.println( "The result of " + numA + " and " + numB + " is : " + result);
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue.....(y) or (n)?");
    choise = cho.nextLine();

    if(choise.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        System.out.println("Welcome back.....:)\n\"Make By Saikat Halder\"");
        status = true;}
    if(choise.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
        System.out.println("Good bye....Thanks for useing java Calculator......:)");
        System.exit(0);

        }
    }
}
```

}